# Pass stored procedure results to List in VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list

I have a current stored procedure that returns email address, password, and app id.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ClientLogin_AppIdPasswordRequest]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Email varchar(100)=''
AS
BEGIN
    Select tblApp.EmailAddress, tblApp.Password, tblApp.ID from tblApp 
    where (@Email=EmailAddress)
END
```

The problem is that an email may have multiple app ids associated to it. The current way that I am passing this information to VB.net is as follows but only returns the first app id.

```
        Try
            Dim oDR As SqlDataReader
            Dim oCMD As New SqlCommand
            Dim sEmail As String
            Dim sPassword As String
            Dim sID As List(Of String)
            oCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email)
            oCMD.CommandTimeout = 0

            oDR = ExecReader(oCMD, "ClientLogin_AppIdPasswordRequest")
            If oDR.Read Then
                'Found
                sEmail = CNull(oDR("EmailAddress"))
                sPassword = oDR("Password")

                ' Should populate an array or list but only returns first id
                sID = oDR("ID")

                ' Do stuff here
            End If

            oDR.Close()
            oCMD.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Catch
        End Try
```

How do I get a result list of all the app ids that are associated with an email that is passed in?

Comment: You can replace if... by while odr.read ...

Comment: Use a dataset, and then you will automatically have your list.

Comment: One other thing: Avoid discarding the Exception as you're doing above. It will most definitely come back and bite you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that your call to ExecReader takes care of the details to connect to the database and passing the correct paramenter then you could change your code to

```
Dim dt = New DataTable()
oDR = ExecReader(oCMD, "ClientLogin_AppIdPasswordRequest")
dt.Load(oDR)
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    'Found

    ' Now you have a DataTable where every DataRow represent one record
    ' retrieved by you procedure
    For Each dr in dt.Rows
       sEmail = CNull(dr("EmailAddress"))
       sPassword = dr("Password")
       sID = dr("ID")
       ' do your stuff with this sets of data,

    Next
End If
' The datatable dt is still available for further processing here
```

This approach could be used if you need to keep your found rows in memory to execute further operations on them after the closing of the connection. Instead if you process everything immediately before closing the connection you can use
a loop directly on the records returned by the DataReader

```
oDR = ExecReader(oCMD, "ClientLogin_AppIdPasswordRequest")
while oDR.Read

   sEmail = CNull(oDR("EmailAddress"))
   sPassword = oDr("Password")
   sID = oDR("ID")

End While
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic idea:

```
    If Not oRD Is Nothing Then

        If oRD.HasRows Then

            While oRD.Read

                'your working here

            End While

        End If

    End If
```